# How to synchronize access inside async for?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I found this library for asynchronously consuming kafka messages: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka

It gives this code example:

```
from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer
import asyncio

async def consume():
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        'redacted',
        bootstrap_servers='redacted',
        auto_offset_reset="earliest"
        #group_id="my-group"
    )
    # Get cluster layout and join group `my-group`
    await consumer.start()
    try:
        # Consume messages
        async for msg in consumer:
            print("consumed: ", msg.topic, msg.partition, msg.offset,
                  msg.key, msg.value, msg.timestamp)

    finally:
        # Will leave consumer group; perform autocommit if enabled.
        await consumer.stop()

asyncio.run(consume())
```

I would like to find out the biggest kafka message using this code. So, Inside `async for` I need to do `max_size = max(max_size, len(msg.value))`. But I think it won't be thread-safe, and I need to lock access to it?

```
try:
    max_size = -1
    # Consume messages
    async for msg in consumer:
        max_size = max(max_size, len(msg.value)) # do I need to lock this code?
```

How do I do it in python? I've checked out this page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html and I'm confused because those synchronization primitives are not thread-safe? So I can't use them in a multithreaded context? I'm really confused. I come from a Java background and need to write this script, so, pardon me that I haven't read all the asyncio books out there.

Is my understanding correct that the body of the `async for` loop is a continuation that may be scheduled on a separate thread when the asynchronous operation is done?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250609/discussion-on-question-by-pavel-orekhov-how-to-synchronize-access-inside-async-f).

Answer (score -1):

asyncio code runs on a single thread. Hence, your understanding is wrong, the for loop logic wont be scheduled on a different thread.

Moreover, even if it was multithreaded, you are updating a local primitive which is saved on the stack. Stacks are not shared between threads.